# RANCID saving config lines out of order

Tags: switch, brocade, backups, rancid

On one of the configs backed up by RANCID, it has switched two lines. Lines 241 and 242, for example, have been swapped. It does this every time the backup is grabbed, and it only happens on this single switch.

On the (brocade) switch itself, the config is correct, both the running config and the boot config.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This was due to the ACLSORT option in the RANCID config.